# Java warning: "The serializable class Info does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long" and 2 errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 1 warning and 2 errors in my java program:

Warning: The serializable class Info does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

Error 1: Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

Error 2: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

Code:

```
package mainPackage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Info extends JFrame {  //<-----Warning: "The serializable class Info does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long"
//Variables
boolean Is64Bit = false;
boolean IsWindows = false; //<-----Error 1:"Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token"

//Bits
if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Mac OS X"))
{
    IsWindows = false;
}
if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Lunix"))
{
    IsWindows = false;
}
else
{
    IsWindows = true;
    if (System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("amd64"))
    {
        Is64Bit = true;
    }
    if (System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("x86_64"))
    {
        Is64Bit = true;
    }
}
//Define Objects on Screen
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
JLabel hello = new JLabel("Hello " + System.getProperty("user.name") + "!", JLabel.LEFT);
JLabel OSlabel = new JLabel();
if(IsWindows)
{
    if(Is64Bit = true)
    {
        OSlabel = new JLabel("Your Operating System: " + System.getProperty("os.name") + " 64 bit.");
    }
    if(Is64Bit = false)
    {
        OSlabel = new JLabel("Your Operating System: " + System.getProperty("os.name") + " 32 bit.");
    }
}
else
{
    OSlabel = new JLabel("Your Operating System: " + System.getProperty("os.name") + ".");
}   //<-----Error 2:"Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block"

public Info()
{
    super("Computer Info");
        //Window
            setSize(350, 100);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, 1, 10, 10);
            setLayout(layout);
            FlowLayout layout1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
            row1.setLayout(layout1);
            row1.add(hello);
            add(row1);
            GridLayout layout2 = new GridLayout(1, 1, 10, 10);
            row2.setLayout(layout2);
            row2.add(OSlabel);
            add(row2);
            setVisible(true);
}
private static void setLookAndFeel()
{
    try
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel
        (
            "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NumbusLookAndFeel"
        );
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        //ignore error
    }
}
public static void main(String[] arguments)
{
    Info.setLookAndFeel();
    Info frame = new Info();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest problem is that you have executable statements that aren't in a method, which isn't allowed in Java.  All the code above the `Info` constructor needs to be in a method.

On an unrelated note, you've misspelled "Linux".

Answer (score 0):

1) If a bracket is expected after a semi colon (the punctuation for the ending of a line) then it is probably a method or constructor, not the end of a line of code.

2) Add another end bracket.  Again, make sure that for every beginning bracket there is an end bracket.

EDIT: One and two might be fixed at the same time by pairing up your brackets.

3) Serialized classes should have a serial ID, even if you don't use it.

4) I assume you are new here.  Try debugging things yourself before asking online, including checking the errors in the console to see if any lines come up with errors.